# Can't delete a user from database by clicking delete button on the same page

Tags: php, mysql

I searched fot the solution but nothing works.

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, EmailAddress FROM users", $connection);

echo "<form method='post'><table class='mecz' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>
<tr>
<th>user names:</th>
<th>address e-mail</th>
<th></th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr align='center'>";
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['EmailAddress'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input class='delete' type='submit' name='delete' value='usuń' /></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></form>";
```

//here a part when i'm trying to pass delete action from the form

```
?>
<?php

if (($_POST['username'] != "") && (isset($_POST['delete'])))  
{
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND '".$_POST['delete']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$connection);
echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

I think the solution is not very complex but i can't find it, please help.

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you attempt to execute the delete query?

Comment: Try removing the `AND '".$_POST['delete']."'"` and see if that helps.

Comment: Your form-element is missing the `action`-attribute which specifies the page you want to 'post' the data to. So if you want to send it to the same page, `action='#'` should do the trick.

Comment: @Quasdunk: If you don't specify the `action` attribute, the form POSTS to itself.

Comment: @Blender Alright, didn't think about that :)

Answer (score 3):

1. you aren't sending `username` in the code you posted, so `$_POST['username']` isn't set and thus the delete isn't executed.
2. even if you would enter the `if`-block, your delete-query doesn't make much sense - what should `AND '".$_POST['delete']."'` do? that part seems pretty sensless.
3. you try to make one form containing several submit-buttons (one for every user). on server-side you can't determine wich submit-button is pressed as the whole form gets sent as one big bunch of data. you'll need one form per user or simply use links (`a`-elements) to sent the `delete`- and `username`-values (but note that in the latter case you'd do `GET` instead of `POST`-requests)
4. you don't specify a `action` for your form - this might or might not be a problem in your case, please see the various comments to your question about this for more information.
5. your delete-query is perfectly open for [sql-injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). please consider using [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or at least [`mysql_real_escape_sting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid this.

and this are only the real problematic points that prevent your code from working at all or leave awkward security-holes. in addition, there are some things that are just unneccessary or some kind of messy (like calling `mysql_error` every time instead of doing that only if a query fails - but maybe you just added that for debugging).

altogether it seems like you should start reading a good book or some detailed tutoriala again to refresh and extend your fundamental understanding of php/mysql/html.

Comment: I was thinkig that .$_POST['delete']. could describe that the delete button was clicked

Comment: but what should that do in the mysql-query?